# Supply parameters to grep via execl, not working; possible format problems of the string

Tags: c

Im trying to call grep via execl. After forking and piping indata to the new process via stdin i try this:

```
execl("/bin/grep","grep","PATH",0);
```

And it works. However i want to be able to use the parameters from

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {}
```

I then try:

```
execl("/bin/grep","grep",argv,0);
```

And call the program by writing "./program PATH" in the console, but it doesn't work; the grep process exits with exit status 256. I think the problem is the format of the parameter. Argv is an array of null-terminated char*, and maybe the grep call doesnt like that.

I also want there to be more than one word as parameter; so that you could call "./program -z PATH" for example. How to fix it?

The whole code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int childExitStatus=0,childPID=0;

    int cpipe0[2];
    if(-1==pipe(cpipe0)) {
        printf("Pipe failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Fork printenv
    childPID=fork();
    if(-1==childPID) {
        printf("Fork failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (0==childPID) {
        if (-1==dup2(cpipe0[1],1)) {
            printf("Pipe failed");
            exit(1);
        }

        close(cpipe0[0]);

        execl("/usr/bin/printenv","printenv",0);

        printf("Execl failed");
        _exit(1);
    }
    close(cpipe0[1]); // Close pipe0 write end
    wait(&childExitStatus);
    printf("Printenv exited with status: %d\n",childExitStatus);
    if(childExitStatus!=0) {exit(1);}


    // Fork grep
    childPID=fork();
        if(-1==childPID) {
        printf("Fork failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (0==childPID) {
        close(cpipe0[1]);
        if (-1==dup2(cpipe0[0],0)) {
            printf("Pipe failed");
            exit(1);
        }

        execl("/bin/grep","grep","PATH",0); 
        // change to: execl("/bin/grep","grep",argv,0);
        printf("Execl failed");
        _exit(1);
    }
    wait(&childExitStatus);
    printf("Grep exited with status: %d\n",childExitStatus);
    if(childExitStatus!=0) {
        printf("No matching environmental variables in GREP for supplied parameters\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're allowed to write into your own `argv`. You can overwrite `argv[0]` with `grep` (provided your `strlen(argv[0]) >= strlen("grep")`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to call `execv()` if you'll be passing an array. The first item in the array should be the program name, and the last must be NULL, so create a modified `argv[]`:

```
else if (0==childPID) {
  const char **myArgs = NULL;
  int i;

  close(cpipe0[1]);
  if (-1==dup2(cpipe0[0],0)) {
    printf("Pipe failed");
    exit(1);
  }

  myArgs = calloc(argc + 1, sizeof(char *));
  myArgs[0] = "grep";

  for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i )
    myArgs[i] = argv[i];

  myArgs[argc] = NULL;

  execv("/bin/grep", myArgs); 
  printf("Execv failed");
  _exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Why `calloc()` when all of it gets initialized afterwards?